# Can't make modal view appear right in the center of the screen on iPad iOS6

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6, modalviewcontroller, uimodalpresentationformsh

I have a problem with modalviewcontrollers that I want to represent on iPad screen. If I leave the size as it is, then it's all centred fine. But I have very few info on these views, so I need to resize them.

So, when I resize them, I can't force them to appear in the middle of the screen. Even if I manage to center one of them in one orientation, it's messed up in other one.

Here is my current code:

```
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:acvc];
[nav setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
[nav setModalTransitionStyle: UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
[[acvc view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"main_bg.jpg"]]];
[self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
nav.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2 + 175, self.view.bounds.size.height/2 - 125, 350, 250);
// nav.view.superview.center = self.view.window.center;
```

Would appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: I tried your code (with that last line uncommented out), and it centered fine in both orientations. What result do you see?

Comment: @rdelmar If you run this code while in portrait orientation on iPad it is shown centred, and if you rotate the screen from that in will stay centered. But! If you run it in landscape mode first it will be very left and low in the screen and then it will stay like this even if you rotate the screen to portrait.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your last line to the following:

```
nav.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 350, 250);
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you. I think I tried this already and it didn't work, maybe I did something wrong...

Answer (score 7):

Here's a method that works on **iOS7** as well as iOS6 and iOS5 and still allows you to use **UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical**:

```
-(void)presentController:(UIViewController*)controller fromRootController:(UIViewController*)rootController withSize:(CGSize)size
{
    UINavigationController* nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
    nav.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    [rootController presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)
    {
        nav.view.superview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        nav.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    }
    else
    {
        nav.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Stopped working in iOS7, unfortunately.
Only changing ModalTransitionStyle to Dissolve solves the problem. Maybe it's a bug in iOS 7...

Answer (score 0):

in ios 7 you can use :

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    self.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

it works.